# How to keep user's settings without having him to authenticate on a mobile app

Tags: sqlite, authentication, mobile, settings

Given a mobile app with no authentication, I was looking for the most suitable way to keep user's setting without any authentication. That mean in my database I won't have a user table to link with another table keeping his settings.

I thought about a in-app database such as sqlite. But I'm afraid that with some manipulation it get erased when the user turn off his phone.

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if it's your application and you can modify it, then use the device IMEI and create a table to save settings for that device. 
If you don't want to create a table then i suppose the only option is to save it locally on device but like you said there is a chance that might get wiped away so best bet is to keep it on server. As device IMEI won't change you can always check it at first startup and retrieve settings.

Comment: With a quick search I saw that one can't access IMEI on iOS (for Android it will be fine I guess). Another option would have been the UUID but since iOS7 also it's not permit of access either. Well if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I guess you are right. Didn't realise they don't allow it anymore. How about a user's iCloud email or Game Center ID ? If you can access that then its possible to use it to create a unique id for each user?

Comment: can you develop more please ?